# Replace all the same values in a hash map at once

Tags: java, object, pointers, reference, hashmap

Let's say that I have a HashMap that looks like this:

1 -> A

2 -> B

3 -> B

4 -> A

5 -> A

6 -> B

with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 being the keys and A, B, C being values.

What I would like to do is replace all values of B with the value of A in the HashMap in a single step (without having to iterate through the elements 2, 3, and 6 and putting the value of A for every single one).

Basically, I would like to remove the object B and everywhere where B is referenced, to replace it with A. I think that in C/C++ this can be achieved using pointers. How can I do it in Java?

Comment: Do you mean without iterating, or do you mean without *explicitly* iterating? If the latter, `map.replaceAll((k, v) -> v.equals("B") ? "A" : v);`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, that's just not what hashmaps do or what they are for.

There are no data structures anywhere in the core libraries that can do this, in fact.

An easy, optimal route is to use mutable objects as values. For example:

```
Map<Integer, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder("A");
map.put(1, a);
map.put(2, a);
a.clear();
a.append("b");
System.out.println(map);
```

The above would end up printing "{1: b, 2: b}". Of course, if you make 2 separate stringbuilder objects, each containing the text 'a', changing one would NOT change the other.

[Guava](https://guava.dev) has bimaps, which are 2-directional, but the general idea is that both keys and values are unique and you obviously don't have that here. Guava also has multimaps, which map one key into multiple values; you could use such constructors to handroll something here, too: Have a data structure that consists of both a `HashMap<K, V>` as well as a `Multimap<V, K>`; the hashmap is as above, the multimap does the reverse, and maps, in your example, `B` to the values `2`, `3`, and `6`, which you can then use to somewhat efficiently write a method that will do the job of 'replace all values equal to THIS with THAT', by looking up which key(s) need replacing in the multimap, then replacing those k/v pairs in the map, as well as updating the multimap.

Note that this is still multiple steps, is O(n) where n is the # of matching keys, and cannot be done in a multithread-safe way without rather heavy handy synchronized() locks around most of the API of your collection.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just maintain a second Map with String to Set so that you can maintain 2 -> B, 3 -> B, 6 -> B and B -> [2, 3, 6].

```java
Map<String, Set<Integer>> letterToKeys = new HashMap<>();
```